# Deriving a DUPLICATION FORMULA by beta functions

Tags: vector-analysis

May you please prove that $B(n,n+1)=2^{-2n}B(n,1/2)$ and hence derive the duplication formula. I'm totally clueless on how to prove that because I lack enough resources to master the concept. Please help!

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LegendreDuplicationFormula.html

Answer (score 0):

Recalling the relationship between the Beta and Gamma functions, $B(x,y)=\frac{\Gamma(x)\Gamma(y)}{\Gamma(x+y)}$, we can write

$$\begin{align}
B(n,n+1)&=\frac{\Gamma(n)\Gamma(n+1)}{\Gamma(2n+1)}\\\\
&=\frac{n!\,(n-1)!}{(2n)!}\tag1
\end{align}$$

Next, using the functional relationship $\Gamma(x+1)=x\Gamma(x)$ repeatedly reveals

$$\begin{align}
\Gamma(n+1/2)&=(n-1/2)(n-3/2)\cdots (1/2)\Gamma(1/2)\\\\
&=\left(\frac{(2n-1)(2n-3)\cdots (1)}{2^n}\right)\,\Gamma(1/2)\\\\
&=\left(\frac{(2n)(2n-1)(2n-2)(2n-3)\cdots (2)(1)}{(2^n)(2^n\,n!)}\right)\,\Gamma(1/2)\\\\
&=\left(\frac{(2n)!}{2^{2n}n!}\right)\Gamma(1/2)\tag 2
\end{align}$$

Using $(2)$ in $(1)$ we obtain

$$B(n,n+1)=2^{-2n}\frac{\Gamma(n)\Gamma(1/2)}{\Gamma(n+1/2)}=2^{-2n}B(n,1/2)\tag 3$$

as was to be shown!

---

From $(3)$, we can derive the duplication formula $\Gamma(n)\Gamma(n+1/2)=2^{1-2n}\Gamma(1/2)\Gamma(2n)$ in a straightforward fashion.  From $(3)$ we have

$$\frac{\Gamma(n+1)}{\Gamma(2n+1)}=2^{-2n}\frac{\Gamma(1/2)}{\Gamma(n+1/2)} \tag 4$$

Rearranging $(4)$, we find that

$$\Gamma(n+1)\Gamma(n+1/2)=2^{-2n}\Gamma(1/2)\Gamma(2n+1) \tag 5$$

Using the functional relationship $\Gamma(x+1)=x\Gamma(x)$ in $(5)$ yields

$$n\Gamma(n)\Gamma(n+1/2)=2^{-2n}\Gamma(1/2)(2n)\Gamma(2n)\tag 6$$

Simplifying $(6)$, we obtain

$$\Gamma(n)\Gamma(n+1/2)=2^{1-2n}\underbrace{\Gamma(1/2)}_{=\sqrt{\pi}}\Gamma(2n)$$

which can be rearranged to give

$$\Gamma(2n)=2^{2n-1}\frac{\Gamma(n)\Gamma(n+1/2)}{\sqrt \pi}$$

And we are done!

Comment: Then how do you derive the DUPLICATION FORMULA by the right hand side (RHS) of the equation?

Comment: I've edited to provide this last piece.

Comment: I understand what you edited, the duplication formula is

Comment: @seanjohnphasikacele Pleased to hear.  And please feel free to up vote and best vote as you see fit.  -Mark

Comment: I don't understand what you edited, because the duplication formula that I know is  r(2n)=(2^(2n-1)r(n)r(n+1/2))/(27/2)^(1/2) . Note (27/2)=pie ....It is not what you found. In short, please derive the duplication formula by the beta function that you proved in the beginning and ended at (3),and then prove from the right hand side(RHS) result to yield the duplication formula that I just recently gave you!!!!

Comment: @SeanJohnPhasikaCele I cannot read the equations in your comment.  But $\Gamma(1/2)=\sqrt{\pi}$ and the formula I derived is precisely the duplication formula for the Gamma function [See here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#General).

Comment: I've made some changes to help shed light.  Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can. -Mark

Comment: Now,I understand!!!!!

Comment: Sean, since you're new to the site I wanted to let you know that you can up vote and accept it by selecting the check mark.

Comment: How do you vote and select check mark?

Comment: Sean, on the left-hand side of the answer box, you should see a gray-colored panel with up and down arrows and a check mark below them. -Mark

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\mrm{B}\pars{n,n + 1} & =
{\Gamma\pars{n}\Gamma\pars{n + 1} \over \Gamma\pars{2n + 1}} =
{\Gamma\pars{n}\Gamma\pars{n + 1} \over
\pars{2\pi}^{-1/2}\,2^{2n + 1/2}\,\Gamma\pars{n + 1/2}\Gamma\pars{n + 1}}
\label{1}\tag{1}
\\[5mm] & =
2^{-2n}\root{\pi}{\Gamma\pars{n} \over \Gamma\pars{n + 1/2}} =
2^{-2n}\,{\Gamma\pars{n}\Gamma\pars{1/2} \over \Gamma\pars{n + 1/2}} =
2^{-2n}\,\mrm{B}\pars{n,{1 \over 2}}
\label{2}\tag{2}
\end{align}

> In \eqref{1}, I used the *Gamma Duplication Formula* and in \eqref{2} I used the well known result $\ds{\Gamma\pars{1 \over 2}} = \root{\pi}$. See the
>   [A & S Table](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_256.htm).